# Adding a time based trigger using an add-on throws an error that does not exist when running the same code in the editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I have included the code below. The issue is that when the 'createTestTrigger' function is run from the editor the function runs, creates the trigger, and the trigger runs. However, when I "Test as add-on" with a spreadsheet and run it from the add-on menu it fails with the following error:

> Unexpected error while getting the method or property create on object ScriptApp.ClockTriggerBuilder.

This only seems to fail when running as an add-on. I tested it as part of a project in a workbook and that worked fine as well. I cannot find any documentation that would confirm my suspicions that Google simply does not allow add-ons to create triggers but I cannot find anything.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createAddonMenu();
  menu.addItem('Test trigger creattion', 'createTestTrigger')
  menu.addToUi();
}

function createTestTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('toBeTriggered')
  .timeBased()
  .after(5000)
  .create();
}

function toBeTriggered(e) {
  Logger.log('Ran from trigger: ' + e.triggerUid);
}
```

Comment: What are your Addon scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from Google documentation:

> Installable triggers aren't supported when testing. Functionality that
>   depends on installable triggers are not testable.

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons#testing_details

You can *not* install a time based trigger when using the "Run - Test as add-on" menu item.

The best way to develop your add-on is by creating a bound script to the document, and running it that way.  For example, if it's a Sheets add-on, from the Sheets menu, click "Tools - Script editor" and a new Apps Script project will open and automatically be bound to the spreadsheet.

The problem with developing an add-on from a bound script, is that if you want to publish your add-on from a stand-alone script, then you need a way to transfer all the files from the bound project to the stand-alone project.  You won't want to manually copy and paste files.  One way to do that is with the Chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo?hl=en

Upload to GitHub from the bound project then download from GitHub to the stand-alone project.

Related Note:
A time trigger created by an add-on can only run once per hour at most:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers

An add-on can not install one time-based trigger, and then 10 minutes later delete the first trigger and then install another time-based trigger.

Comment: I completely missed that quoted text. I'll see if they run when the add-on is deployed. Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing "Unexpected error while getting the method or property setValue on object SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadata" with a time-based installable trigger for a published add-on, and when testing in a bound script.

My add-on allows users to configure (add, edit, delete) a once-daily trigger to update a Sheet, and it was working when I published. When  you say "An add-on can not install one time-based trigger, and then 10 minutes later delete the first trigger and then install another time-based trigger", does that apply even if the first time-based trigger was not actually executed?

Comment: A time based trigger that was installed by an addon can only run once every 61 minutes.  If the previous trigger has not run yet, I'm not sure if the addon can delete it, and then create a new trigger with a scheduled run time that is within that 1 hour window of the last scheduled trigger time.  I guess you'd need to test it to know for sure.  I don't know why there would be a connection between the metadata setting error and the trigger.  You'll probably need to get some better error information from your error handling.